# Correct route used just URLs are wrong. MVC 3 routing.

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller

I'm creating a commerce site and I've run into the issue of multiple categories inside categories. My ActionLinks are going to the right category but sometimes they put a redundant querystring at the end. This doesn't always occur, only when in a sub-category(I understand the actionlink attempts to to pull routevalues from anywhere but see below)

I've dumbed it down a bit to make sure I'm not missing anything but I'm having the same problems:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Store1",
    "store/{tier1Category}/{tier2Category}/{categoryId}",
    new { controller = "Store", action = "Index"},
    new { categoryId = @"\d+" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "Store",
    "store/{tier1Category}/{categoryId}",
    new { controller = "Store", action = "Index"},
    new { categoryId = @"\d+" }
);
```

I've created a HtmlHelper extension for Category links:

```
public static MvcHtmlString CategoryLink(this HtmlHelper helper, Category category)
{
    .........

    return helper.ActionLink(category.Name, "Index", "Store", new { tier1Category = tier1Category, tier2Category = tier2Category, categoryId = category.CategoryID }, null);
}
```

(The sniped code just gets the tier1Category & tier2Category)

So on the home page I've a Navigation menu, an example would be:

http://localhost/store/tshirt/1

Now if I was to go into a subcategory of this category (http://localhost/store/tshirt/men/2) the same link in the navigation would be:

http://localhost/store/tshirt/1?tier2category=men

Now what makes this more confusing is that when I debug the extension method above, in this scenario, the action link that is returned is "http://localhost/store/tshirt/1" i.e. Correct! So there seems to be something happening with the MvcHtmlString that is returned from the extension by the time it spits out the html. Also it should be noted that the link still goes to the correct location.

Any help would be great as I'm kinda pulling my hair out here...

Answer (score 0):

I created a project with this exact code inserted.  Of course I replaced the dots in the helper with code to populate the missing variables.  The urls generated came out exactly as you wish for them to, not with the query string.  So on that note, who knows.

As for the problem at hand however, it feels a little weird to me that you are including the `categoryId` in the url at all.  Isn't that what the category strings are supposed to handle?  If that's the case, you can tighten things up a bit with a single store route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Store",
    "store/{tier1Category}/{tier2Category}",
    new { controller = "Store", action = "Index", tier2Category = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Now you aren't doubling up information in your url and you can use the number at the end for either paging or something else useful.  And I would argue that the urls look cleaner:

http://localhost/store/tshirt
http://localhost/store/tshirt/mens

Comment: If it's any use the problem is occurring on a tier1Category index page view in which the _layout contains a partial view; Navigation view containing all the categories.


In terms of the id in the URL string I was originally using your method, I decided to go the other route because I felt the linq query was a bit overkill:

Comment: when retrieving the category. i.e. Drilling down from tier1Category to tierXCategory. I do agree it looks cleaner and it is a gripe of mine.